# Winsock + C + Client to Client + Send And Receive Data

Tags: networking, architecture, client-server, firewall, nat

I'm a pretty simple question. I implemented a system where can send data between two clients without using a direct connection between them (without opening ports in the firewall on clients), following this model:

Client 1 ------> Server ------> Client2
Or
Client 1 <------ Server <------ Client2

There is nothing wrong with this model that is working ok. The problem is that the overhead on the server increases considerably, because it needs to receive data from a client, and then immediately forward to the next.

My question: is there a faster way to send data between clients? Or send data from client to another without using a direct connection between them?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but not trivial to establish direct connections between clients with the centralized server's help.  This is called [Nat Traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal) and works by punching holes in the firewalls using "fake" UDP packets.
The technique was pioneered (or at least brought to the forefront) by Skype.
See the Wiki article for links and general overview of how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I was looking at the "UDP hole punching", and this seems simple enough to be implemented. The only problem is I need to maintain a certain integrity to send / receive data, because the software I'm developing is a shell where commands must be sent in the correct sequence, and download / upload files must be accurate.

Comment: So it would be more interesting for my case using "TCP hole punching". Suppose I use this method, I would need a server S, and two clientes: C1, C2. C1 and C2 are connected to S. S identifies the address of the client and sends the information for each one thereafter a client become aware of each other.

What I did not understand this whole process is as follows: how to connect a client with the other, if clients are already connected to the server, and their doors are locked it?

Answer (score 0):

1 - your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with c/c++/winsock.

2 - You're probably doing it the best way possible right now, as load increases you only need to scale up your server (as opposed to making horribly complex clients that attempt to connect point to point)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I was looking at the "UDP hole punching", and this seems simple enough to be implemented. The only problem is I need to maintain a certain integrity to send / receive data, because the software I'm developing is a shell where commands must be sent in the correct sequence, and download / upload files must be accurate.

Comment: So it would be more interesting for my case using "TCP hole punching". Suppose I use this method, I would need a server S, and two clientes: C1, C2. C1 and C2 are connected to S. S identifies the address of the client and sends the information for each one thereafter a client become aware of each other.

What I did not understand this whole process is as follows: how to connect a client with the other, if clients are already connected to the server, and their doors are locked it?